# webService php+json

Tags: php, json, aplicação-web, libcurl

Olá!

Gostaria de ajuda para integrar com webService via url, por exemplo:

```
$list_result = '{"titulo": '. 
  '[{"id":$id_primary}'.
']}';

$json = json_encode($list_result);

//echo $json;

//API Url
$url = 'https://local-que-devo-enviar.com.br/arquivo';



$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))
);


//retorno   
$jsonRet = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); 

var_dump($jsonRet);
```

- Gostaria de ajuda para compreender se estou montando o array de dados corretamente, como faço para obter um retorno e se o código fica dessa forma. Porque não estou recebendo retorno do webservice...

Comment: Você está usando um `json_encode` de uma coisa que já "está como" um JSON?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está no caminho, mas desviou no momento de criar o JSON que está enviando..

Para codificar algo em JSON com PHP você deve passar um array como parâmetro. Altere as primeiras linhas para isso, teste e diga o resultado nos comentários para refinarmos nossa resposta:

```
$list_result = array(
    'titulo' => array(
        array(
            'id' => $id_primary,
        ),
    ),
);

$json = json_encode($list_result);
```

Ah! E, adicione isso nas configurações da sua requisição para visualizar mais dados sobre a resposta do servidor:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

E, tem que fechar o curl no final e perceba que eu removi a função `json_decode` nesse momento apenas para verificar a resposta do servidor que está com cabeçalho:

```
$jsonRet = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($jsonRet);
```

Comment: percebi que preciso de um grupo e um subgrupo na matriz.. como ficaria isso...                                                                                                          
    {  
   "teste":9999,
   "teste":99999,
   "teste":"LINDL0001",
   "itens":[  
      {  
         "item1DoTeste1":{  
            "item1":"123",
            "item2":11,
            "item3":"22/09/2006",          
         },
         "item2DoTeste1":{  
            "a":123,
            "b":"2 x",
            "c":3,
            "d":"s 44",
         },

Comment: Consegui montar com essa idéia. Ficou legal, só o retorno que não nada concreto.. com o var_dump, aparece bool(false)

Comment: Testei novamente, agora estou recebendo um retorno consistente.. Sendo assim, resolvido!!! Obrigado!!! =D

Comment: Se vc puder me mostrar mais detalhes de como capturar o retorno de dados, acho q vou precisar.. =/

Comment: e vc já viu um erro no retorno chamado: 'businessException' ?

Comment: businessException deve ser um erro que o WebService que está tentando consumir está gerando. E, quando a captura de dados depende dos dados, o retorno é JSON, XML, HTML.. ao invés de utilizar var_dump utiliza print_r e se há alguma dúvida específica, crie uma nova pergunta e não esqueça de apresentar o contexto e informar o código que está trabalhando!!

Comment: Ah! E quanto a exceção busque a documentação da API ou um contato com os desenvolvedores para entender o que aconteceu de errado para essa exceção ser gerada.

Comment: Perfeito... e sobre os dados, gostaria por exemplo de capturar um nome vindo do webservice, que será baseado em um id q enviei por exemplo. Com json/php/html...

Comment: Ahh, e para enviar token e informações desse tipo no header da estrutura, sabe em q posição do código fica? (tendo como base a estrutura postada no inicio)

Comment: Aqui tem tudo o que pode configurar http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php. E para adicionar cabeçalho a opção é o CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER que deve receber um array de strings

Comment: E, sobre capturar um nomo vindo do webservice.. isso é muito amplo não tem como responder. Faça novas perguntas específicas e com exemplos que sempre vai existir alguém tentando responder.

Answer (score 0):

percebi que preciso de um grupo e um subgrupo na matriz.. como ficaria isso...
    {
   "teste":9999,
   "teste":99999,
   "teste":"LINDL0001",
   "itens":[
      {
         "item1DoTeste1":{
            "item1":"123",
            "item2":11,
            "item3":"22/09/2006",
         },
         "item2DoTeste1":{
            "a":123,
            "b":"2 x",
            "c":3,
            "d":"s 44",
         },

Comment: A questão do colchete no grupo e subgrupo consegui, ainda tô testando ;

Comment: Essa parte dos colchetes ficou resolvida tbm.